# INSERT INTO and the subquery with COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, subquery

I'd like to put photo data to the table `articles_photos` and condition it with numbers of photos for selected article.

Both tables exist. Below I have presented my query

```
INSERT INTO articles_photos(title, 
                            filename, 
                            photo_order, 
                            created, 
                            article_id) 
      VALUES ('title', 
              'filename', 
               (SELECT COUNT(id) 
                  FROM articles_photos 
                 WHERE article_id = 7) + 1, 
              NOW(), 
              7)
```

phpmyadmin says:

```
Static analysis:

5 errors were found during analysis.

    A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "SELECT" at position 109)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "COUNT" at position 116)
    Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 121)
    Unexpected token. (near "id" at position 122)
    Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 124)

#1093 - Table 'articles_photos' is specified twice, both as a target for 'INSERT' and as a separate source for data
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: You can't use the same table in a subquery that you are inserting data. The error is clear: `#1093 - Table 'articles_photos' is specified twice, both as a target for 'INSERT' and as a separate source for data`

Comment: Should I use two separate query, get the number of rows and then make the second query? Can I do what I described in one query?

Comment: The answer from JNevill is just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. I believe the following will work:

```
INSERT INTO articles_photos(title, 
                        filename, 
                        photo_order, 
                        created, 
                        article_id) 
SELECT 'title', 
    'filename', 
    COUNT(id)+1, 
    now(), 
    7
FROM articles_photos 
WHERE article_id = 7;
```

You should be able to SELECT from the same table upon which you are inserting, but you can't do it in a subquery inside your `VALUES` list like you had in your question. Instead, here, we just move all the constants down into the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I just test the query and you give the answer. I lost by you only for 38 seconds. And you miss `+1` at the count.

Comment: @MahediSabuj It happens to me a lot. I tend to be more thorough than many of the other posters here and end up losing the race often. Every once in a while I can squeak one in first. Just added the + 1.